# How to import the Android OS source code (e.g. frameworks/base) into Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, frameworks, operating-system, android-source

I want to work on Android source code. Here is all versions of Android's source codes are listed.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/

Why I do that. Because when i import some of classes, they need others and there will be lots of errors. So I guess, importing entire project to the eclipse will be a solution.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try Android Studio, should have no problem importing projects there, and its way smoother to use for Android projects than Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to git clone the repository and then import the source code in eclipse.

In eclipse, choose File> Import. Select appropriate.

Follow this tutorial https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html. Come back if you face any issues.

Comment: Well Normally it should.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to build AOSP code in ecllipse. Android has not mentioned anywhere about building AOSP code in Eclipse. You can build it from terminal only.

However you can use eclipse to make code changes or for offline code debugging. Go to File > New Java Project >  >

Answer (score 0):

AOSP source code is too complex to wrap in an eclipse project like projects you encounter with IDEs. What worked for me is to use eclipse for browsing AOSP code and to debug framework applications. But the actual building of AOSP code was done in a bash shell session.

Please check the Setup section of [Debugging Android Framework applications](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) link.